# How to properly send Python code?

Tags: python, virtualenv, file-transfer

So I want to send my python script to another computer, nonetheless, it doesn't have the same package installed on it. Is there any way to send the whole python code as a folder which will also include all that packages? ( I have tried creating a virtual environment through the problem relies on the fact that a lot of the code in the virtual environment is made of aliased files which might not exist on the other computer).
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: You have a `requirements.txt` file

Comment: @Tobias what do you mean

Comment: https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Comment: @phd Not really the same, OP wants to send the "code", not to run it independently. Could be for a colleague to review it.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a `requirements.txt` file, here will be all your packages from your project, if you have already vitualenv for example to create your `requirements.txt` execute

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

example of `requirements.txt`

```
absl-py==0.2.1
amqp==2.3.1
asn1crypto==0.24.0
```

after this take your all project without your virtualenv, copy to another compure create a new virtualenv, enter in your virtualenv and make

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

you will have all your packages

Comment: Oh I see, what I wanted to know if there is a possibility to directly send everything in a folder? (also is it a good idea to transfer virtual env folders from one computer to an other)  Thank you very much

Comment: no is a bad idea to transfer your virtualenv folder from one computer to another

Answer (score 0):

Barring the longer process of creating an installable package with a `setup.py` file, you can place your script in its own folder, then add a pip requirements file. *While your virtualenv is active*, run the bash/terminal command:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Ensure that you send the requirements file with the script, and then the recipient can simply run the bash/terminal command (in their own virtualenv, which they hopefully will do)

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

before running the script.

Comment: Oh, someone beat me to it.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, does a setup.py automatically installs all the files?

Comment: @Fozoro: Yes, but it's not really intended for standalone scripts since it installs a package in the active python environment. I don't think it would suit your needs in this situation.

Comment: oh I see so if you were to sell a python script you would just send the requirements.text file and the .py files? or you would also send the virtualenv folder?